# Truncate parent table in Oracle when child table is empty

Tags: oracle, referential-integrity, truncate

Suppose I have a parent table `parent` referenced by a child table `child`. The table `parent` is populated but `child` is not. Attempting to truncate `parent` results in

```
 ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
```

Is there a way to hint to the DBMS that `child` is empty, so that the foreign key constraint doesn't need to be disabled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no such hint.
What you can do is

```
alter table {child_table} disable constraint {fk_constraint_name};
truncate table {parent_table};
alter table {child_table} enable constraint {fk_constraint_name};
```

Answer (score 8):

The [restrictions on truncating tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10007.htm) include:

> You cannot truncate the parent table of an enabled foreign key
>   constraint. You must disable the constraint before truncating the
>   table. An exception is that you can truncate the table if the
>   integrity constraint is self-referential.

This is presumably because truncate is DDL and doesn't do any checks on data in the target table, even to see if it has any rows. It would have to do that DML, and look for any matching rows in all child tables (or at least check there are no rows), etc, which would change the nature of the command and potentially impact performance. And it would have to consider uncommitted transactions against the child tables, which would have expected an error on insert rather than commit if the constraint wasn't defferred.

The only way to do this is to disable or drop the constraint, as @ik_zelf shows.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way round the restriction with `truncate` as other answers have indicated, but you can of course use `delete` without disabling the constraints:

```
delete from parent;
```

Note that 'delete' and 'truncate' [have different side-effects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36615/1396)