# Why is truncate DDL?

Tags: oracle, delete, ddl, truncate

I have an interview question, which was asked during my interview. I answered the question, but interviewer was not so convinced with my answer. So, anyone please correct me with my understanding ?

**Q. Why Truncate is DDL Where as Delete is DML ? Both do almost same job (removing rows)**

Ans. When we are using Truncate, we are de-allocating the whole space allocated by the data without saving into the undo-table-space. But, in case of Delete, we are putting all the data into undo table-space and then we are deleting all the data.

Please, if anyone knows best answer for the above, please explain.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64752/discussion-on-question-by-ravi-why-is-truncate-ddl).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The DML versus DDL distinction isn't as clear as their names imply, so things get a bit muddy sometimes.

Oracle clearly [classifies `TRUNCATE` as DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30041) in the Concepts Guide, but `DELETE` as DML.

The main points that put `TRUNCATE` in the DDL camp on Oracle, as I understand it, are:

- `TRUNCATE` can change storage parameters (the `NEXT` parameter), and those are part of the object definition - that's in the DDL camp.
- `TRUNCATE` does an implicit `commit`, and cannot be rolled back (flashback aside) - most (all?) DDL operations in Oracle do this, no DML does.

The fact that `TRUNCATE` doesn't run `ON DELETE` triggers also sets it apart from normal DML operations (but some direct path DML operations also skip triggers, so that's not a clear indicator).

That same documentation notes that `DELETE` generates UNDO, but `TRUNCATE` doesn't, so your statement is correct in this respects. (Note that `TRUNCATE` does generate some `REDO` so that the truncation can be replayed in case of restore/recovery.) But some `NOLOGGING` operations can also produce reduced UNDO (not sure about none at all), so that's not a clear indicator either in my opinion.

So I'd sum it up as:

- `truncate` is not "transactional" in the sense that it commits and can't be rolled back, and can modify object storage attributes. So it's not ordinary DML - Oracle classifies it as DDL.
- `delete` is an ordinary DML statement.

Comment: When you create a table, you can specify things like what tablespace it goes in, initial size, next extent size, etc. Those are storage attributes. Yes, they're part of a table's (or index, or partition) metadata.

Comment: Note that the SQL standard lists TRUNCATE in the chapter "Data manipulation" together with INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `truncate` is similar to `drop`, `alter`, `create` as they 
 all work on a table i.e. they all are table level commands.
While 'delete' is similar to `insert`, `select`, `update`as the all work on a rows i.e. they all are row level commands.

Answer (score 1):

Delete deletes the data, Truncate also does the same. Then why truncate is a DDL command since it is acting on data, ideally it should also be under DML. This has been most asked in interviews. It is because when we apply truncate internally it drops the table first then re-creates the schema/structure of that table. It is because of this Truncate is a DDL command..So Truncate is DROP+CREATE action

Comment: Can you please share any refrence where this nature of truncate is documented ?