# "TRUNCATE doesn't run ON DELETE trigger" true or false

Tags: mysql, trigger, ddl, truncate, mysql-5.0

I was searching on the topic of why TRUNCATE is placed in DDL instead of DML for which I found following answer here
[Why is truncate DDL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/why-is-truncate-ddl)

I this answer I found a sentence as given below

"The fact that TRUNCATE doesn't run ON DELETE triggers also sets it apart from normal DML operations"

This conflicts with [MYSQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) which says

"If the FOREIGN KEY constraint specifies DELETE CASCADE, rows from the child (referenced) table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes empty."

I am in a confused state. Please elaborate on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you interested in? And which version of the documentation are you reading from and referring to?

Comment: MYSQL 5.0 , just edited the question with links check out

Comment: The link to the manual you posted is pretty cleaer: "*the TRUNCATE TABLE statement does not invoke ON DELETE triggers*"

Comment: Yeah! indeed it does but the point of confusion is statement from 3rd para i.e "In the case that FOREIGN KEY constraints reference the table, InnoDB deletes rows one by one and processes the constraints on each one. If the FOREIGN KEY constraint specifies DELETE CASCADE, rows from the child (referenced) table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes empty." Isn't ON DELETE CASCADE is a trigger.

Comment: The rows are deleted, but the delete _trigger_ is not fired

Answer (score 4):

Your first link ([Why is truncate DDL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/why-is-truncate-ddl)) is about Oracle, not MySQL. While relevant, different DBMS implement same features differently. In Oracle and SQL Server `TRUNCATE` is DDL, not DML.

In MySQL, it matter which version you use:

- **Until [version 5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html)**, the documentation says:

> Logically, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is **equivalent** to a `DELETE` statement that deletes all rows, but there are **practical differences** under some circumstances.
>
> For an InnoDB table:
>
> - If there are no `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, InnoDB performs fast truncation by dropping the original table and creating an empty one with the same definition, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one.
> - When you use this fast truncation technique with the `innodb_file_per_table` option enabled, the operating system can reuse the freed disk space. For users of the InnoDB Plugin, the space is reclaimed automatically, as described in Reclaiming Disk Space with `TRUNCATE TABLE`. If you do not have the InnoDB Plugin installed, issue the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` statement to free the disk space for the table.
> - **If there are any `FOREIGN KEY` constraints** that reference the table, InnoDB processes `TRUNCATE TABLE` by **deleting rows one by one**, **processing the constraints** as it proceeds. If the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint specifies `DELETE CASCADE`, rows from the child (referenced) table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes empty. If the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint does not specify `CASCADE`, the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement deletes rows one by one and stops if it encounters a parent row that is referenced by the child, returning this error:
>
>   ```
>   ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign  
>   key constraint fails (`test`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1`  
>   FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))
>   ```

But **for [versions 5.5 and later](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html)**, the documentation says:

> Logically, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is **similar** to a `DELETE` statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements. To achieve high performance, **it bypasses the DML method** of deleting data. Thus, **it cannot be rolled back**, it **does not cause `ON DELETE` triggers to fire**, and it **cannot be performed for InnoDB tables with parent-child foreign key relationships**.
>
> Although `TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to `DELETE`, **it is classified as a DDL statement** rather than a DML statement. It differs from `DELETE` in the following ways in MySQL 5.5:
>
> ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The documentation states otherwise (for Postgres http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-caveats.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For SQL Server: [TRUNCATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) I made no remarks about being possible to roll it back in other DBMS (only for MySQL).

Comment: I hope that you read my comment above, I am only concerned with, whether ON DELETE triggers are processed by TRUNCATE or not and if not (as appears in documentation) than what is "ON DELETE CASCADE"   a ON DELETE trigger or something else.

Comment: @geeksal do you use InnoDB or other engine?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ InnoDB

Comment: @geeksal frankly, I don't know. I assume they wouldn't run but I'm not sure. But it should be fairly easy to test (if other triggers, not the `CASCADE`, are triggered)! I don't have a 5.1 installed in my machine, I'll try later.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is no point in debating, if you have reliable proof that TRUNCATE is DML (specifically from documentation) than please post it or left your point here itself.

Comment: @geeksal a_horse has a point. I removed the Postgres part from my answer (until I'm sure what it is there)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thanks! I'll be waiting for your reply and in mean time I will also try it. Also please let me know that whether for different version of MYSQL the concept varies or not. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: That's already in the answer. In versions 5.5 or later, if there is a foreign key that references a table, you cannot TRUNCATE that table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that we reach conclusion regrading the different versions. But  for the version until 5.1documentation  says " Since truncation of a table does not make any use of DELETE, the TRUNCATE TABLE statement does not invoke ON DELETE triggers. " but in para 3 it clearly says that InnoDB invokes ON DELETE CASCADE trigger. Hence it conflicts here.